# Sumif Based on Multiple Criteria and Text Color

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I am using a Macro to Sum up Values of a specific Debtor.  It currently works fine but I need to add another Criteria;

```
Range("DebtorList_Payed")=Application.SumIf(Range("InvoiceList_Table_ItmCode"), _
  Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), Range("InvoiceList_Price"))
```

I have another Range on the Invoice List Worksheet called Range("InvoiceList_Payed") in this row there is "CASH", "CREDIT", "(Custom) CASH" & "(Custom) CREDIT".

The text in the "CASH" & "(Custom) CASH" Rows is Green
and the text in the "CREDIT" & "(Custom) CREDIT" Rows is Red

Using the existing Macro I need for it to only sum the Rows which in the corresponding Range("InvoiceList_Payed") the Text Color is Green,

So something like;

```
Range("DebtorList_Payed")=Application.SumIf(Range("InvoiceList_Table_ItmCode"), _
  Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), Range("InvoiceList_Price") = _  
  Range("InvoiceList_Payed")> "Green"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Excel 2007 or later you can use the SUMIFS function, and if you're in an earlier version you can nest the SUM and IF functions.  The real problem is that there is no way to get the color of the cell from a worksheet function.  You can use the CELL("color", REF) function IF AND ONLY IF the formatting on the cells is set so that the Green is positive and the Red is negative (or vice versa).

Of course, this would be easy to do using standard VBA functions/properties like RGB.

You could also just trigger off of the word "CASH" since both Green rows have that in common.

Example:

```
SUMIFS(Range("InvoiceList_Payed"), Range("InvoiceList_Table_ItmCode"), _  
  Range("Debtor_list_Debtors"), Range("InvoiceList_Payed"), "*CASH*")
```

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010, so how would I achieve this?

Comment: @James, It depends on which method I was referring to that you wanted to use. I'll edit in an example, but I'm not completely sure from your question of the exact details.  Note the order of the parameters change from SUMIF to SUMIFS.

Comment: Thank you so much Lance, a major thing that willl help with several of my macro's is "*CASH*" rather than "CASH" so it works as containing rather than specific, that solved the issue, again muchly appreciated, thank you.